# can we perform auto scaling for instance groups in gcp based on request count or response time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Hi I am new to gcp and interested to learn if the auto scaling of gcp instances can be done based on request count or response time?

The idea is we will be investigating this and will write terraform scripts to perform this action?

Thanks!

I have done investigation so far from gcp documentation but i have hit a wall so far.
Didn't find any information that helps me with the solution.

Comment: Which GCP instances are you referring to?

Comment: In `Autoscaling policy` https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler#target_utilization it is also mentioned that you can scale using `requests per second` or  by using `Cloud Monitoring metrics`. Please do note that improper scaling policy, can directly increase your billing amount without proper resource utilisation.  Kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you. I am referring to gcp instance webserver group